# Using "Attach to Process" for debugging

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-debugging

I want to debug an issue that does not happen when I run my application from `VisualStudio` but it does happen when I run it directly from `localhost`. It is a Silverlight app.

So I thought I should use `"Attach to process"` to find out what is going on.
So I run my application directly from `localhost` - not from VS - and then in VS I pick Attach to process and select my `localhost` process. But it never hits my breakpoints. 
Is there some other settings I am missing to be able to debug it this way?

[image]

Comment: Have you tried using `System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Attach()`?

Comment: Your lcoalhost must have the latest dll's.

Comment: @Hatsjoem What do you mean and how do I make sure it does? I assume everytime I compile my app, it gets updated?

Comment: @martin_costello No I have not, how and where? Do you have an example?

Comment: If you add that to a Debug version of the application and run it, it *should* pop up a dialog after it starts requesting you attach the debugger to the process.

Comment: @martin_costello My VS doesn't have such a method. It only auto-completes "System.Diagnostics.Debugger.IsAttached" for me.

Comment: Sorry, it should be `Debugger.Launch()`. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.diagnostics.debugger.launch%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are running a Silverlight app, you'll have to attach to the browser that is hosting the  XAP (IE, Chrome, etc) in order to attach to the code.

Comment: Well that is what I am doing.

Comment: Are you sure it's the correct IE process? There are multiple browser processes.

Comment: I added a screen shot of what I pick from processes to my question. Thanks .

Comment: Make sure you are including the Silverlight code type when you attach. Only x64 is selected in your localhost ie instance